# Finding the running difference between elements in the same index of different sublists within a nested list

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, iteration, nested-lists

I have a nested list, through which I must iterate and compare (and subsequently operate with) elements in the same position/index of each sublist. For example, here is a minimum reproducible program:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [1,4,7], [2,0,8], [5,1,1]] #nested list

b = [[1,2,3], [0,2,4], [1,-4,1], [3,1,-7]] #desired output
```

I need to essentially create a new nested list, where each subsequent sublist in the solution is the difference between the sublist in the same position/index in the original nested list and the sublist in the position/index before in the original nested list. i.e., the first sublist in b is just the first sublist in a, the second sublist in b is the second sublist in a subtract the first sublist in a, the third sublist in b is the third sublist in a subtract the second sublist in a, ...., and the nth sublist in b is the nth sublist in a subtract the nth-1 sublist in a.

I need to do this in an automative and iterative manner since these lists I've provided above are not the real lists - the real nested lists contain thousands of sublists. I am new to python so if this is very simple I apologise - if this is the case, if you could direct me to a solution I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a = [[1,2,3], [1,4,7], [2,0,8], [5,1,1]] 
b = [a[0], *[list(i) for i in np.diff(a, axis=0)]]
```

Alternatively, if you want to use pure Numpy methods then

```
b = np.ndarray.tolist(np.r_[[a[0]], np.diff(a, axis=0)])
```

Comment: Iterating `numpy` arrays is antipattern. It works slower that iterating lists and therefore should be replaced with `numpy` methods.

Comment: You're right, but I would prefer using my solution, just for the sake of code readibility. Of course my opinion would change if I had to deal with millions of sublists made of hundreds of items. I timed 100 iterations of both approaches with 10K sublists made of 300 elements. Pure numpy took 21.2 seconds, hybrid took 24.7. So imho, yes, but it depends (need also to mention that for the presented case, the full numpy is much slower).

Comment: So, the thing you observed was actually a relatively small number of iterations. `np.diff` did near 3M of operations in both cases and it took near 20 seconds. In my case, you don't need to iterate it extra 10k times. In hybrid solution it took 3 seconds more to do that. If you really need more readable solution, try this: `np.diff(a, prepend=[[0,0,0]], axis=0).tolist()`. `prepend` parameter is new in version 1.16.0, added for better code readability.

Answer (score 1):

[`np.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) is designed for it:

```
import numpy as np
b = np.r_[[a[0]], np.diff(a, axis=0)]
```

Note that output is `numpy` array. It works much faster than standard Python iterations.